# Ajax recarga de sitio

Tags: php, ajax

Buen día estimados, les cuento:

Estoy desarrollando un modulo para *prestashop*, el cual tiene un par de *inputs* para el calculo de tarifas, esto me esta funcionando correctamente pero ahora estoy en la parte donde arreglo un poquito el código.

Tengo ésto en un *JS*:

```
function calculateCost(){

        var deliveryRegionId    = $('#deliveryRegion').val();
        let deliveryRegionName  = $('#deliveryRegion').find('option:selected').text();
        var deliveryComunaId    = $('#deliveryComuna').val();
        let deliveryComunaName  = $('#deliveryComuna').find('option:selected').text();
        let deliverySucursalId  = $('#deliverySucursal').val();
        let deliverySucursalName= $('#deliverySucursal').find('option:selected').text();
        var idDelivery          = $("input[type=radio][name=cch_option]:checked").val();
        var deliveryAddressName = $("#deliveryDireccion").val();
                                               
        
        $.ajax({
            url:   './modules/cch_shipping/process.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type:  'post',
            data:
            {
              deliveryRegionId     : deliveryRegionId, 
              deliveryRegionName   : deliveryRegionName,
              deliveryComunaId     : deliveryComunaId, 
              deliveryComunaName   : deliveryComunaName,
              deliverySucursalId   : deliverySucursalId,
              deliverySucursalName : deliverySucursalName,
              id_delivery          : idDelivery,
              deliveryAddressName  : deliveryAddressName
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#loading-circle").show();
              $("#lock-modal").show();
            },
            success:  function (response) {

              switch (response){
                case 'ERR_DIR_N_NORM':
                  alert('Dirección no normalizada, intente nuevamente');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                  break;
                case 'ERR_NOM_CMNA':
                  alert('Comuna incorrecta, intente nuevamente');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                  break;
                case 'ERR_NOR_DRCCN':
                  alert('Ingrese una dirección válida');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                break;
                case 'OK':
                  location.reload();
                break;
              }

            }
        });
```

Por *JS* manejaba que al hacer click a un `button type=button` tomara los valores de los inputs **(que no estaban en un form)** y luego con ajax los mandaba a *PHP*. Lo malo, es que al hacer click en el boton tenia que usar *reload* para recargar el sitio y así poder ver los cambios.

Ahora, buscando más la perfección sabía que si yo estos *inputs* los dejaba dentro de un *form* podía utilizar `$('form').submit(function(e){});` entonces saque la funcion y deje todo dentro de esto, quedando asi:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    

        var deliveryRegionId    = $('#deliveryRegion').val();
        let deliveryRegionName  = $('#deliveryRegion').find('option:selected').text();
        var deliveryComunaId    = $('#deliveryComuna').val();
        let deliveryComunaName  = $('#deliveryComuna').find('option:selected').text();
        let deliverySucursalId  = $('#deliverySucursal').val();
        let deliverySucursalName= $('#deliverySucursal').find('option:selected').text();
        var idDelivery          = $("input[type=radio][name=cch_option]:checked").val();
        var deliveryAddressName = $("#deliveryDireccion").val();
                                               
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url:   './modules/cch_shipping/process.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type:  'post',
            data:
            {
              deliveryRegionId     : deliveryRegionId, 
              deliveryRegionName   : deliveryRegionName,
              deliveryComunaId     : deliveryComunaId, 
              deliveryComunaName   : deliveryComunaName,
              deliverySucursalId   : deliverySucursalId,
              deliverySucursalName : deliverySucursalName,
              id_delivery          : idDelivery,
              deliveryAddressName  : deliveryAddressName
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#loading-circle").show();
              $("#lock-modal").show();
            },
            success:  function (response) {

              switch (response){
                case 'ERR_DIR_N_NORM':
                  alert('Dirección no normalizada, intente nuevamente');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                  break;
                case 'ERR_NOM_CMNA':
                  alert('Comuna incorrecta, intente nuevamente');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                  break;
                case 'ERR_NOR_DRCCN':
                  alert('Ingrese una dirección válida');
                  $("#loading-circle").hide();
                  $("#lock-modal").hide();
                break;
                case 'OK':
                  
                break;
              }

            }
        });

  });
```

Adicionalmente agregue el *prevent* para que no se recargara el sitio. Ésto funciona pero solo cuando se cumplen las 3 condiciones del *switch* previas al "OK", necesito que cuando sea "OK" el sitio se recargue de manera natural, sin utilizar el `location.reload();`.

Desconozco si es posible, favor si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

> pd: Es mi primer posteo en stackoverflow, espero haberlo hecho correctamente y con claridad.

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo en particular por el que no puedas o quieras usar `location.reload();`?

Comment: @JosueArriola Si, me paso con la primera solución que aplique en el desarrollo, cuando presionaba el boton se llamaba la función y luego hacia el reload, con esto habian momentos en que la informacion no lograba cargarse en la bd sin embargo le agregue un settimeout de 12 segundos aprox, y con esto me "aseguraba" de cierta forma.. Ahora, podria usar el reload, pero nose si me podría pasar lo mismo, si no existe una opción u otra forma de hacerlo veré como funciona, aunque de momento en las pruebas no he tenido problemas.

Comment: @JosueArriola Por el momento lo dejare con location.reload(); esto debido a que, entendiendo un poco mas como funciona ajax, en el back haré las validaciones para que la información sea insertada antes de que sea enviada la respuesta de vuelta al ajax. Así que no debería ocurrir lo que te mencioné con anterioridad. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: tal como tu lo mencionas, las validaciones debes hacerla del lado del servidor y en el response enviar los errores o un indicador de que todo se hizo correctamente, te voy a compartir en una respuesta lo que yo uso para recargar sin necesidad del `location.reload();`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el ejemplo que utilizo para hacer lo que mencionas, solamente debes hacer las validaciones del lado del servidor y si no hay errores a la hora de guardar los datos en `process.php` colocas un `echo "0";`, sino un `echo` del error, el cual vendría en `response`, en mi ejemplo uso [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) para mostrar el mensaje, obviamente eso es opcional igual que la parte inferior en la que uso los eventos `ajaxStart` y `ajaxStop` para mostrar el loader para evitar usar `beforeSend`. Ojala te sirva.

```
$.ajax({
    url:   './modules/cch_shipping/process.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    type:  'post',
    data:
    {
      deliveryRegionId     : deliveryRegionId, 
      deliveryRegionName   : deliveryRegionName,
      deliveryComunaId     : deliveryComunaId, 
      deliveryComunaName   : deliveryComunaName,
      deliverySucursalId   : deliverySucursalId,
      deliverySucursalName : deliverySucursalName,
      id_delivery          : idDelivery,
      deliveryAddressName  : deliveryAddressName
    },success: 
    function (response) { 
        if(response == "0"){
        Swal.fire({
        position: 'top-end',
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Información guardada',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500}).then(
        $('form').fadeOut(800, function(){
        form.html(response).fadeIn().delay(2000);
        }););
      }
      else {
        Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'No se ha guardado la información',
        html: response});
      }
    }
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$("#loading-circle").show();
$("#lock-modal").show();})
.ajaxStop(function(){
$("#loading-circle").hide();
$("#lock-modal").hide();});
```

Comment: Gracias! no conocía sweetalert, aproveche probarlo y me gusta, visualmente le da un estilo muy entretenido... te agradezco por todo.